How to create user in appwrite using flutter?
I'm facing problem in user creation. In appwrite it creates user in auth section but throws that type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List'.
Code:
 Future<User> createUser({
    required String email,
    required String password,
    required String name,
  }) async {
    print(email.runtimeType);
    print(password.runtimeType);
    print(name.runtimeType);
    try {
      User user = await account.create(
        userId: ID.unique().toString(),
        email: email.toString(),
        password: password.toString(),
        name: name.toString(),
      );
      print(user);
      return user;
    } on AppwriteException catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar("Error", "Failed to create user: $e",
          colorText: Colors.white);
      rethrow; // Handle the error
    } finally {
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

Image:

User created in auth section:

